# Azure Sitecore 9.0.1 XP1 Paas XConnect 500 errors after DNS CNAME and SSL cert added to Site

Tags: azure, xconnect

I have a Pass Powershell Arm installed Sitecore 9.0.1 XP1 install.  Verified that analytics were working (Collecting and reporting visits in the Experience Analytics Dashboard.  We installed DNS CNAME entries and corresponding SSL certificates for the new domain names and we are now getting 500 server errors on the Experience analytics pages.  Has anyone encountered this?  Is there another step required to configure XConnect for the new DNS names?

Comment: Can you check your logs and report what the errors are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES application setting in on your app service in azure. It should correspond to the certificates used by xConnect and not your custom certificates. You can also set this value to * to load all the certificates.
[image]

Be aware that these settings are filled in by the ARM templates and scripts. So you may need to adapt your script. Our script got corrupted by adding a second certificate because the call to fetch the certificates returned an array instead of the single certificate. We had to adopt the script.

The value should correspond with the value in your connection string.
StoreName=My;StoreLocation=LocalMachine;FindType=FindByThumbprint;FindValue=<<some-value>>;AllowInvalidClientCertificates=true